# Can you kill a Tk app from another thread? If not, is it possible to easily send a boolean message to main thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I was writing a Tk application (my first one) and as you can tell, I'm new to python. I basically needed a thread to not block the main thread where the Tk instance is running, so I'm downloading the file in another thread.
Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import Toplevel, FLAT, BOTH, X, IntVar, StringVar, HORIZONTAL, Text, END, Tk, LEFT, RIGHT
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Frame, Style, Button, Checkbutton, Progressbar, Entry
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import os
import sys
import threading
from shutil import copyfile, rmtree
class DownloadWindow:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        self.master = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close)
        self.master.geometry("600x400")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        frame = Frame(self.master, relief=FLAT)
        frame.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill=BOTH)
        self.mode = 'unksize'
        self.progressbar = Progressbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='indeterminate')
        self.progressbar.pack(fill=X)
        self.progressbar.start(20)
        self.downloaded = 0
        self.progressv = Text(frame, bd=0, insertborderwidth=0, state='disabled', background='#f0f0ed', font=('Segoe UI', 10))
        self.progressv.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=(10,5))
        self.downloading = threading.Thread(target=self.download)
        self.downloading.start()
    def download_progress(self, count, block_size, total_size):
        if total_size != -1 and self.mode != 'ksize':
            self.mode = 'ksize'
            self.progressbar.stop()
            self.progressbar.configure(mode='determinate', maximum=total_size)
        elif total_size == -1 and self.mode != 'unksize':
            self.mode = 'unksize'
            self.progressbar.configure(mode='indeterminate')
        if self.mode == 'ksize':
            self.downloaded += block_size
            self.progressbar.step(block_size)
            if self.downloaded == total_size:
                self.progress('Download ended.')

    def download(self):
        self.pathres = False
        self.progress('Downloading...', False)
        # Let's suppose this failed
        messagebox.showerror(title='uh oh this failed', message='Download failed, error bla bla bla')
        self.error_close()
        self.progressbar.stop()
        self.finish()
    def finish(self):
        self.progress('The installation is finished...')
    def progress(self, what, lb=True):
        self.progressv.configure(state='normal')
        self.progressv.insert(END, ('\r\n' if lb else '')+what)
        self.progressv.configure(state='disabled')
    def error_close(self):
        # This is technically the method that's called when the download fails with an error
        # This closes the window, but not the console itself... You can check that in taskmanager or from console if running from it...
        self.root.destroy()
    def close(self):
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    DownloadWindow(root)
    root.withdraw()
    root.mainloop()
```

*^ Runnable example*
The problem is: how can I exit the app on the part when I caught the error?
Basically I tried self.root.destroy() but as you can tell, it didn't work (it closed the window but the mainloop continued running), tried sys.exit() it didn't work neither (I think it killed the new thread instead of the "main" one), and I passed the root Tk() to the other thread too, but it didn't work neither.
You can run the example above to understand more.
I've put a print right after the root.mainloop method and once the thread called the root.destroy, strangely, it printed the exit string... So, I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: I use `root.destroy()` or `root.quit()` to close my GUI. I never use `sys.exit()`. That said your example is not testable. Portions of code are missing in order to run your example.  Please provide all imports and root window.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I added the various imports and the main method, and as I said, I already tried those methods, but being in another thread, it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then yes. Here is a short example where a button in the threaded window kills the app in the main thread.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread


root = tk.Tk()


def threaded_window():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Button(top, text='kill main application in main thread', command=root.destroy).pack()


tk.Button(root, text='Open threaded window', command=lambda: Thread(target=threaded_window).start()).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't have a threaded window, I have a threaded process, and it's from this that i want to stop everything... But, you made me think of something...

Comment: @Pato05 same concept with or without a window. Just a command from the thread to destroy the root window should work.

Comment: already tried it as you can see in the error_close function, but the only thing that closes is the window, not the mainloop...

Comment: Well, anyways, if you move the root.destroy() in another function, that will kill only the windows, not the mainloop...

Comment: Like, replace the button arg command with "a" and do an a function that calls root.destroy(), that won't work... Why?